# FLUTTER Checkbox UI not updating

Tags: flutter, checkbox, flutter-layout

I have of many checkboxes as You can see the image uploaded, please see the image first.

[image: PLEASE SEE THE IMAGE FIRST AND AFTER THAT YOU CAN UNDERSTAND MY PROBLEM]

Now the problem is that you can see the 3 cards views Conditions, Allergies and Past Surgeries. and all of these cards contains checkboxes and now what happens is that when I check or uncheck any box the UI of the CheckBox doesn't update to tick or untick and I have checkboxes outside the build method.

Can anyone let me know that what am I doing wrong and I will share the checkboxes codes also?

**EDIT**

**CREATING CHECK BOXES DYNAMICALLY**

```
List<Widget> _dynamicListWidget(List<dynamic> list) {

 List<Widget> widgetList = List<Widget>();
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  Condition condition = list[i];
  widgetList.add(
    Container(
      width: _containerWidth,
      //padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: Text(condition.name, style: _textStyle),
          )),
          //Expanded(child: Container()),
          Checkbox(
            value: condition.selected,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              print("$value  value");
              setState(() {
                condition.selected = value;
              });
              addRemoveFavHealth(value, condition.id);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
return widgetList;
```

}

**CREATING A CARD VIEW**

```
 Widget mainbody(String name, List<dynamic> dynamicList) {
final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final screenheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
print("$screenWidth width of device");
List<Condition> list = List();

return Container(
  width: screenWidth * 0.49,
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          //width: 200,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black12,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    child:
                        /*Image.asset(
                                        'assets/icons/doc_icon.png'),*/
                        Icon(
                      Icons.playlist_add_check,
                      color: AppTheme.primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        _localization.localeString(name),
                        style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.primaryColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: _dynamicListWidget(list),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

**BUILD METHOD**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  _localization = AppTranslations.of(context);

  return Expanded(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: _mainList,
      ),
    ) 
  );
}
```

In the build method, _mainList is the list of the MAINBODY METHOD.

Comment: "what happens is that when I check or uncheck any box the UI of the CheckBox doesn't update to tick or untick and I have checkboxes outside the build method." What do you mean you have checkboxes outside the build method? It seems you may need to share more code with us and what the "condition" variable is.

Comment: @JoãoSoares what I meant is that the condition is that as you can see that many checkboxes and with tick and untick, so what happens when I untick the box with already ticked boxes it doesn't change the to untick, and it remains tick and vice-versa.....and for the build method I will add more code to make you understand.

Comment: You are facing this problem because you did some mistake in `onChanged` property inside `CheckBox` (the conditions you have provided is wrong in some way). So please add some more code so that we can help you

Comment: You must be getting some message in the terminal when you press any checkbox, can you add that?

Comment: @HardikKumar I am not getting any message in the terminal as you can see that there is a print command in onChange it prints if was false initially then it prints true for the value and doesn't change the UI of the checkbox and when I press again the same checkbox it prints the same true value, so it means that checkbox is not updating itself or the value is not changing

Comment: `List<Condition> list = List();` after this line, you are not filling the `list`. And then you are passing it to the `_dynamicListWidget()` method here `children: _dynamicListWidget(list)`. Then how is the data being displayed? Is some more relevant code missing in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are assigning your "condition" value inside the `for loop` and then expecting that when you do `setState` to change it, that it will reflect on the original list of conditions. Here I have an example of using a `ListView.builder` instead of a `for loop` with a column to produce the same effect, but correctly changing the value of the variable on the external list And in parallel your approach:

[See the code running here on DartPad](https://www.dartpad.dev/a056fa3cbe82800204beb158ee1ac696)

```
class CheckBox63112014 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckBox63112014State createState() => _CheckBox63112014State();
}

class _CheckBox63112014State extends State<CheckBox63112014> {
  List checks = [
    true,
    false,
    false,
    true,
    false,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('ListView.builder'),
            buildList(checks),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('For loop'),
            Container(
              height: 400,
              width: 100,
              child: ListView(
                children: badList(checks),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(List checks){
    return Container(
      height: 400,
      width: 100,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: checks.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Checkbox(value: checks[index],
            onChanged: (value) {
              print('ListView $index $value');
              setState(() {
                checks[index] = !checks[index];
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> badList(checks){
    List<Widget> widgetList = List<Widget>();
    for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
      bool check = checks[i];
      widgetList.add(
        Checkbox(value: check,
          onChanged: (value) {
            print('For Loop $i $value');
            setState(() {
              check = value;
            });
          },
        )
      );
    }

    return widgetList;
  }
}
```

---

Your code should work if you change it to this:

```
Widget _dynamicListWidget(List<dynamic> list) {
  return ListView.builder(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        width: _containerWidth,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2, bottom: 2),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Text(list[index].name, style: _textStyle),
              )),
            //Expanded(child: Container()),
            Checkbox(
              value: list[index].selected,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                print("$value  value");
                setState(() {
                  list[index].selected = value;
                });
                addRemoveFavHealth(value, list[index].id);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

This would require that where you are using "_dynamicListWidget" needs to expect a `Widget` instead of a `List<Widget>`

Comment: I have implemented this code into my app but still not working but the dart pad you provided and over there it is working

Comment: I couldn't test the modified version of your code. There's just too much data that I don't have. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I am having the same issue while tapping on the check boxes

Comment: Did you understand my explanation and the differences shown on the code example?

Comment: @AnasReza Can you please answer what I asked above? So that I can try to help you.

Comment: Yes I have understood what have you said and I have done exactly the same way that you have shownme

Comment: Could you show me the code as it is now, with the modifications but still not working?